# Inserting HTML into a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to inject the Facebook SDK and a login button onto a webpage, but it's returning an error that I don't understand. I am using the Firefox Add-on Builder. **The ideal solution would be to be able to inject an HTML *file* instead of just the code, but I can't figure out how to do that.** Here is the relevant code on the `main.js`. I know that is correct:

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "http://www.blogger.com/*",
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-latest.js"),
                        self.data.url("blogger.js")]
});
```

And here is `blogger.js`:

```
$('body').prepend(
    '<div id="fb-root"></div>' +
    '<script>' +
    '  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {' +
    '    FB.init({' +
    '      appId      : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", // App ID' +
    '      status     : true, // check login status' +
    '      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session' +
    '      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML' +
    '    });' +
    '    // Additional initialization code here' +
    '  };' +
    '  // Load the SDK Asynchronously' +
    '  (function(d){' +
    '     var js, id = "facebook-jssdk", ref = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];' +
    '     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}' +
    '     js = d.createElement("script"); js.id = id; js.async = true;' +
    '     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";' +
    '     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);' +
    '   }(document));' 
    '$("button.blogg-button.blott-primary").click(function() {' +
    '   FB.login(function(response) {' +
    '      if (response.authResponse) {' +
    '          console.log("Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ");' +
    '          FB.api("/me", function(response) {' +
    '          console.log("Good to see you, " + response.name + ".");' +
    '      });' +
    '      } else {' +
    '          console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");' +
    '      }' +
    '   }, {scope: "publish_actions,manage_pages"});' +
    '});' +
    '</script>'
    )
```

And here is the error (from the Firefox error console):

```
Timestamp: 5/31/2012 8:53:28 AM
Error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/page-mod.js", line 195, in onRead
    self._createWorker(window);
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/page-mod.js", line 203, in _createWorke
    onError: this._onUncaughtError
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/traits.js", line 110, in Trai
    return self.constructor.apply(self, arguments) || self._public;
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/worker.js", line 403, in Worke
    this._contentWorker = WorkerSandbox(this);
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/traits.js", line 110, in Trai
    return self.constructor.apply(self, arguments) || self._public;
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/worker.js", line 202, in WorkerSandbo
    this._importScripts.apply(this, contentScriptFile);
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/worker.js", line 260, in _importScript
    load(this._sandbox, String(uri));
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/sandbox.js", line 43, in loa
    return scriptLoader.loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, 'UTF-8');
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

EDIT: I had forgotten to add a plus sign at the end of a line, but fixing did not fix the problem. However, the error code changed.

```
    '   }(document));' 
    '   }(document));' +
```

New error code:

```
Timestamp: 5/31/2012 9:12:06 AM
Error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/page-mod.js", line 195, in onRead
    self._createWorker(window);
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/addon-kit/lib/page-mod.js", line 203, in _createWorke
    onError: this._onUncaughtError
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/traits.js", line 110, in Trai
    return self.constructor.apply(self, arguments) || self._public;
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/worker.js", line 403, in Worke
    this._contentWorker = WorkerSandbox(this);
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/traits.js", line 110, in Trai
    return self.constructor.apply(self, arguments) || self._public;
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/worker.js", line 202, in WorkerSandbo
    this._importScripts.apply(this, contentScriptFile);
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/content/worker.js", line 260, in _importScript
    load(this._sandbox, String(uri));
  File "resource://jid0-nsaawinaml0b6pn0st2hc4vinxi-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/sandbox.js", line 43, in loa
    return scriptLoader.loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, 'UTF-8');
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking the `<script>` and `</script>` as `'<sc'+'ript>'` and `'</sc'+'ript>'` so it doesn't think the script has ended prematurely.

Comment: For Firefox, using `<\/script>` instead of `</script>` should be enough.

Comment: @user1419007: This would be only necessary inside a `<script>` block of an HTML file - this here isn't one.

Comment: @Wladimir is right; this is a script file. However, that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it. I was being stupid and I had accidentally pasted some text into the file right after fixing the typo in the code (see the edit), and that was causing a syntax error.